# What is the consistency strength of this kind of iterating Berkeley cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

[EDIT] After suggestion from Monroe Eskew, and after having an e-mail correspondence with Prof. Joan Bagaria, I'll re-present the older question as the second in a series of 4 questions. I've had an e-mail correspondence with Prof. Joan Bagaria, and asked him the first of the following 4 questions, and I'll present his answer to it [after taking his own permission on posting it here].

> EDIT: a problem was found with the answer for now, so it'll be presented once its solved, the answer was deleted upon the request of Joan Bagaria himself. So as of now, the first question doesn't have an answer yet.

***Question 1.*** I define Berkeley cardinal in a rank $V_{\kappa}$ as the same definition of Berkeley cardinal but the cardinal itself, the transitive sets and the embeddings involved in its definition all are restricted to be elements of $V_{\kappa}$.

Now if $b$ is a Berkeley cardinal in $V_{\kappa}$, does it necessarily follow that $b$ must be a Berkeley cardinal in the next rank $V_{\kappa +1}$, and more generally does it need to be still a Berkeley cardinal in every higher rank $V_{\kappa^+}$ ?

I personally think the answer is to the negative, but I don't know how to prove it?

***Question 2:*** Is there a clear inconsistency to having an inaccessible set $S$ [i.e., $\bigcup(S)=V_{\xi}$ for an inaccessible $\xi$] of transitive universes $V_{\kappa}$ where each $\kappa$ is inaccessible [where generally $\gamma$ is inaccessible iff  $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal such that $V_{\gamma}$ is not the set union of a subset of it that is not equinumerous to it], such that for each $\kappa$ we have: $$\langle V_{\kappa}, \in ^{V_{\kappa}}\rangle \models ZF + \exists a (a \text{ is a Berkeley cardinal})$$, and such that for each $V_{\alpha}, V_{\beta} \in S: \alpha < \beta $, the first Berkeley cardinal in $V_{\beta}
$ is not a subset of $V_{\alpha}$?

If that is possible, then we can define a new large cardinal property $\xi$ that is the smallest ordinal that is a set of all ordinals in the union set of a set $S$ fulfilling the above qualifications. Call such a cardinal as a ***"Fluctuating Cardinal"***.

***Question 3:*** Supposing that there is no clear inconsistency, then would it be interpretable in $ZF$ plus one of the large cardinal properties mentioned by [Bagaria](https://events.math.unipd.it/aila2017/sites/default/files/BAGARIA.pdf) and [Koellner](http://logic.harvard.edu/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Deep_Inconsistency.pdf)?

***Question 4:***  Can $\bigcup(S)$ be compatible with Choice?

I mean we can arrange for all of the $V_{\alpha}$ stages in $S$ to be non-supertransitive, so we can contemplate having external choice sets on all elements of these stages that do not have internal choice sets (i.e. the choice sets are elements of the next stage, but not of the stage itself), so although choice is not satisfied of course inside each stage $V_{\alpha}$ (because it contains a BC inside it), yet choice can be satisfied outside it, i.e. in the next stage $V_{\beta}$ that is an element of $S$.

By this our $\xi$ fluctuating cardinal would be bigger than all Berkeley cardinals and yet it is not a Berkeley cardinal and yet $\xi$ would be consistent with full choice?

Comment: What sort of thing would count as an answer to the question of whether this is consistent?

Comment: Similarly, what sort of answer are you expecting for the question of its consistency strength?

Comment: for the first comment a proof of its inconsistency, or otherwise interpreting it in a known large cardinal property if consistent, for the second comment proving the least cardinal property that can interpret it

Comment: Berkeley cardinals are beyond anything that has been studied. So asking for a large cardinal property that does the work really makes no sense currently. One could answer the question by saying that the consistency strength is the existence of a proper class of inaccessibles $\kappa$ such that ..., just repeating precisely what you said, and that would be a perfectly reasonable acceptable large cardinal assumption. You need to clarify what you mean. Also, precisely what version of inaccessibility do you have in mind? (We are in a ZF setting, so there are several inequivalent such versions).

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, No there is some hierarchy of cardinals beyond choice, like super-Reinhardt, Club-Berkeley, and others above them. Also it might be possible to derive an inconsistency with what I'm saying for example Berkeley cardinals are closed (i.e. the limit of  Berkeley cardinals is a Berkeley), and perhaps other properties that can destroy what I'm saying here and prove it inconsistent. As about inaccessibility I mean the strong inaccessibility criterion.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of all of that. There is *one* paper on the subject. My point is that your questions are rather premature given that state of affairs. It would be like asking whether supercompactness is consistent when people were barely coming to terms with measurability.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, ah I see what you mean. Well possibly if there is a clear inconsistency then this would justify my question, but if there is non, then I see what you mean.

Comment: By strongly inaccessible do you mean that for each $\lambda<\kappa$, $2^\lambda<\kappa$? (This gives you choice and therefore a contradiction.) Maybe you should mean instead something about how the power set of $\lambda$ relates to $V_\kappa$?

Comment: Does a finite $S$ as above follow from the existence of some number of Berkeley cardinals?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, inaccessibility here is primarily of stages, $\kappa$ is just the mark of a stage of the cumulative hierarchy, so $inaccessible (\kappa) \leftrightarrow \kappa  \text{ is a limit ordinal} \wedge V_{\kappa} \text{ is regular }$, where $V_{\kappa} \text{ is regular }$ is defined as $V_{\kappa}$ not being the union of a subset of it that is strictly subnumerous to it (*strictly subnumerous* here means absence of an injection from it to that subset).

Comment: @MonroeEskew, I don't know, but for the time being I don't see a clear argument against it, i.e. if the inner universe has embedding satisfying Berkeley cardinal conditions, this doesn't mean that the outer universe should obey the same embedding trends.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar— Your question would be more interesting and motivated if you could give examples of things being Berkeley cardinals in one rank, and then failing to be so in a higher rank.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, hmm..., I'll try! Thanks